# How to import Webform configuration using the Webform configuration YAML file

Tags: webforms, 8

I have exported the configuration of a webform 8.x in YAML format.
Now I want to import the configuration file to a webform in a different website as there is no import feature in the Webform.

Any guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are PIs available to help import submission data but you will have to write some custom code.

Below is a very general example of using `WebformSubmissionForm::submitValues` method to import submission data.

```
// Get submission values and data.
$values = array(
  'webform_id' => 'contact',
  'entity_type' => NULL,
  'entity_id' => NULL,
  'in_draft' => FALSE,
  'uid' => '1',
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'token' => 'wmL3nKDgMh91nSTt0ZyohpfgPNITzM_xHvYl_MQQwj4',
  'uri' => '/webform/contact/api',
  'remote_addr' => '::1',
  'data' => array(
    'name' => 'Loremipsum',
    'email' => 'example@example.com',
    'subject' => 'Testing contact webform from Webform Demo Site',
    'message' => 'Please ignore this email.',
  ),
);

// Check that the webform is open.
$webform = \Drupal\webform\entity\Webform::load('contact'); 
$is_open = \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm::isOpen($webform);
if ($is_open === TRUE) {
  // Validate webform submission values.
  $errors = \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm::validateValues($values);

  // Submit webform submission values.
  if (empty($errors)) {
    $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm::submitValues($values);
  }
}
```

If you enable the webform_devel.module and there will be API tab displayed with every webform's 'Test' tab which will generate the need to PHP code snippet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot jrockoeotz. I ll try it today. Will let u know if any issue i face.

Comment: Hi Jrockowtz. One thing i m not clear is i have a yml file in a format that is just like the SUBMISSION VALUES. so do i have to convert all the data in PHP format and paste it in the PHP USAGE BOX. or I just paste the data of the YML file and paste it in the SUBMISSION VALUES and it will be converted automatically. as the data is too much cant convert the whole in the PHP format. Plz guide me.

Comment: There is no UI to directly import submission data.  You need to write custom code and decode the YAML data using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Serialization%21Yaml.php/function/Yaml%3A%3Adecode/8.2.x

Comment: I have a bulk of data in CSV format which i want to import in my Webform 8.x Survey Forms. Please guide me how to do that as I have no easy way out.